# how to calculate 2 digit percentage value using laravel

Tags: laravel-4, percentage

I have a table Main_exam. and fields are mark(int) ,percentage(int) and rank (int)

Iam insert mark percentage and rank to table but my problem is when im calculate my percentage value

is this maxmark=150,obtainted mark=110

% = 110 *100/150 = 73.3333333

but I want 73.33

my code is

`$totalmark = $mainexamreport->sum('mainexam_mark');
$percentagemark = $totalmark*100/$fullmark->sum('maxmark');`

how to change my code?
 I want only correct exact value not rounded value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use number_format of PHP

```
echo number_format($percentagemark,2);
```

Comment: No problem. If the framework does not give you what you want then you can still use some native PHP. Cheers!